# How to process terabytes of data in a timely matter

Tags: parallel-processing, bigdata

**Disclaimer**

I'm a sysadmin for a small shop by trade.

**Situation**

I will receive about 3 TB of data of which each logical unit consists out of

a directory containing:

- a text file in CSV format containing metadata
- a binary file containing the actual data

So in the end I have a massive directory tree with lots of small files.

My job is to transform the metadata file from CSV to XML. I usually resort to Perl to handle this. The newly created XML file will be copied together with the corresponding binary data to a new directory which will be read in by the importer process of a closed-source software package. This import process is serial in nature. It just reads one after the other directory and processes it. The faster, the better.

In the past I just ran several instances of both the Perl transform script and the import process next to achieve some level of parallelization. Now with this 3 TB coming my way I doubt this is going to scale very well.

Hardware wise I have 6 physical machines at my disposal on which I can spin up a limited amount of light-weight VMs (Solaris zones to be specific). I say 'a limited amount' because these machines already run VMs with services.

A last constraint: using any type of cloud service is out of the question due to the sensitive nature of the data.

**Question**

How can I go about this intelligently?. Are there specialized solutions to this? I started looking into Hadoop although I still have to get a handle how it would help with my issue.

I can build in threading in the Perl formatting script and I can run several instances of it to work on different parts of the directory tree. This part I have completely under control.

The part I don't have under control is the importer of the software package - there I am limited to just creating additional instances and watch them plod along.

Any advice on how to approach this would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

1. Estimate time of metadata processing and binary file processing by importer.
2. Recognize bottleneck (taking away most of the processing time) - importer?
3. Replicate/multiply bottleneck resources (importer) - by VM?
4. Write one script (Controler) to control process and script (Worker) for each VM. Controler will be parsing metadata (parallely if needed) and sending  next part of work to Workers (by small config files or by kind of TCP/IP protocol).
5. Or you can use distributed approach without Control scrip but this'll be more difficult to implement.

I think Hadoop will be overkill.